# Why google play store is saved this error of my app

Tags: android, xamarin, in-app-purchase

I received this error in the google play store using the plugin of IAP for android xamarin, but testing the app in varios emulators I can't replicate the error.

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.get_Context () [0x0000e] in <23e2c2cc2c834a60939a94f40f3199b6>:0
at Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.ConnectAsync (Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions.ItemType itemType) [0x00000] in <23e2c2cc2c834a60939a94f40f3199b6>:0
at SellNotes.ShowList.ShowBannerAsync () [0x00025] in <5f3ed89022a54a8eb5a2cc8283f7328f>:0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <5b2cd762a63a490f891d82acf230bd93>:0
at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <39d81d92db3941d9852a6984d1a763db>:0
at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <39d81d92db3941d9852a6984d1a763db>:0
at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <39d81d92db3941d9852a6984d1a763db>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.10(intptr,intptr)
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run (Native Method)
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run (RunnableImplementor.java:30)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7235)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: If this has only happened once then it's literally not worth worrying about.

Comment: like 10 times in the last month